# PHP and SQL INSERT INTO with variables dont works

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

Has anyone an idea of what is wrong in this code?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO quiz.fr_fragen (fr_id, fr_frage, a1, a2, a3, a4, fr_kategorie) 
VALUES ('$id', '$frage', '$a1', '$a2', '$a3', '$a4', '$kat');";
```

Table names are 100% correct. The variables are looking like this:

```
$id = 2002

$kat = 2

$frage = 1+1=

$a1 = 2

$a2 = 3

$a3 = 4

$a4 = 5
```

Previously I created an array from a csv file. The variables are filled correctly, I double checked it.

Comment: You are prone to SQL injection .Use mysqli prepared statement instead of using deprecated mysql function.http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aww...

Use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) as of:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO quiz.fr_fragen (fr_id, fr_frage, a1, a2, a3, a4, fr_kategorie) VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' , '%s', '%s')", $id,  $frage, $a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $kat);
```

I recommend learning about this function and also about data sanitization.

Also between `""` theres a notation of `"{$variable1} and {$variable2}"`, more reliable thant without brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably literally inserting `$id` in your table. Which MySQL returns an error on because it must be a valid integer.

You should look into prepared statements.

`$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO quiz.fr_fragen (fr_id, fr_frage, a1, a2, a3, a4, fr_kategorie) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($id, $frage, $a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $kat);`

Or you could also concat like this, but this ISN'T best practice.

`$sql = "INSERT INTO quiz.fr_fragen (fr_id, fr_frage, a1, a2, a3, a4, fr_kategorie) 
VALUES (" . $id . ", " . $frage . ", " . $a1 . ", " . $a2 . ", " . $a3 . ", ". $a4 . ", " . $kat . ");";`

Answer (score 0):

**Please check out my code**

After that if you faced any problem follow blow links

1.[php_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)

2.[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

```
<?php
$sub = 101;
$mark = 85+5;

$host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db = 'quiz';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password);

if($con){
    if(!mysql_select_db($db)){
        echo "Database not found <br/>";
        die;
    }
}else{
    echo "DB Connect failed";
    die;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO fr_fragen (sub, mark) VALUES ('$sub','$mark')";

echo $sql . '<br/>';

if(mysql_query($sql)){
    echo "Data insert successfully";
}else{
    echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
}

?>
```